# Exterior power of dual space

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a vector space with basis $e_1, \ldots, e_n$ and $V^*$ be its dual space with dual basis $e_1^*, \ldots, e_n^*$. Let $k$ be an integer between $1$ and $n$. Why $\wedge^{n-k}V=\wedge^{k}V^*$? Thank you very much.

Comment: One usually calls $\Lambda^k V$ an *exterior power*, not a wedge product.

Comment: @Mariano, thank you very much.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is slightly false.  The two are isomorphic, but not canonically so.  There is a natural pairing $\Lambda^{n-k} V \times \Lambda^k V \to \Lambda^n V$ given by exterior product, but this pairing does not identify $\Lambda^{n-k} V$ with $(\Lambda^k V)^{\ast}$ until you pick an isomorphism $\Lambda^n V \simeq k$; this implies a choice of [orientation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orientation_(mathematics)), but is slightly stronger; one might say it implies a choice of "volume form."  But it does not imply a choice of inner product.

The (canonical) isomorphism between $(\Lambda^k V)^{\ast}$ and $\Lambda^k V^{\ast}$ comes from the way duals commute with tensor products.  It should look pretty straightforward with a specific basis.

Comment: I retract my last claim conditional on the outcome of the discussion at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44179/signs-in-the-natural-map-lambdak-v-otimes-lambdak-v-to-bbbk/44183#44183 .